# Querytask on multiple inputs - ignore when value is empty

Tags: javascript, query

I am trying to select some features by attributes. This function works correctly:

```
  function executeQueryTask() {          
    query.where = "(xy.zzz.jprl_dop.dv = " + dom.byId("mySecond").value + ") AND (xy.zzz.jprl_dop.DC = " + dom.byId("myOne").value + ")";     
    queryTask.execute(query, showResults);       
}
```

But how to fix situation when one of partial query in function is not set ?

My HTML:

```
<p>One: <input style="width:50px;" type="text" id="myOne" value="" />
                 <p>
                    Second: <select id="mySecond">
                        <option value="">-</option>
                        <option value="1">one</option>
                        <option value="2">two</option>
                        <option value="3">three</option>
                    </select>

                </p>
```

Can someone advice me how to run query in my function when value=" " in option element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an if statement to evaluate if the query value other than ' ' is selected or not:

```
function executeQueryTask() {   
    if (dom.byId("mySecond").value != ' ')  {
        query.where = "(xy.zzz.jprl_dop.dv = " + dom.byId("mySecond").value +    ") AND (xy.zzz.jprl_dop.DC = " + dom.byId("myOne").value + ")";     
        queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
    } else { 
        alert("Select query value!");
    }           
}
```